# using geojson-vt in EPSG:3826

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, geojson

I am a newbie to leaflet.js system. And recently, I meet a problem for future development.
we use geojson-vt to handle canvas drawing in the map which is in EPSG:4326 format. However, for future work, I need to develop system in EPSG:3826, and the first step is using
proj4leaflet.js to project coordinate into EPSG:3826 format, and then my problem is in
such a case, would geojson-vt can still work well via following code snippet:

```
let geojsonvtdata = geojsonvt(geoJsondata);
```

Or there need something more to do another setting for different EPSG format, thanks a lot.